# Need Help Applying Position of Vertices To another

Tags: modeling

My question is in the video following this, but pretty much I need to know how to take the position of points from one side of my object and apply them to the other side without doing every one manually. thanks for the help here is the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBbnMvKVW1s&feature=youtu.be

Comment: cut your mesh at the center, delete 1 half, add a mirror modifier with clipping and merge options checked.

Comment: your model seems to be simple so just delete the back verts and extend the front

Comment: thanks Chebhou im pretty new at this so sometimes i don't think things though entireley, and bithur i would but there will be parts on this that I don't need to mirror, although i guess they could be seperate objects.

Comment: is it done .. ?

Comment: i havent finished the object yet but yes what you said worked